# how browser matches css sub atributes

Tags: css, browser

As documented we can define animation in CSS3 like

```
.class1{
    animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction play-state
}
```

I want to know if I've given value for every attribute like name,duration,timing-function etc other than delay then how browser understand that I've skipped delay property.

then if I've given all the corresponding values for animation property then it is 1:1 matching to attributes and values but if want to skip any intermediate attribute for example

```
.class1 {
    animation: anim 2s cubic-bezier(0 0 1 1) 2 alternate running
}
```

here I've skipped `delay` So how browser get to know that I've skipped `delay` attribute but not the others.

Comment: You need to write more coherently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official W3C draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-shorthand-property) is very sketchy and you will not get a good "official" answer. Basically the browser tries to parse each value according to the specification order, skipping those subproperties that do not match the corresponding value in the `animation` property; so it first sees that the first value is a valid `animation-name`, then the second is a valid `animation-duration`, and goes on until it reaches the value `2`, which is *not* a valid value for `animation-delay`, so it skips `animation-delay` and checks to see if it is a valid `animation-iteration-count`, which it is.

Comment: It seems to be correct but I was trying to set property **background** as **background:#00ff00 url('smiley.gif') 200px 40px  no-repeat fixed border-box** .Now in this case I'm not able to put value for **background-size** which comes after **background-position** (value is 200px 40px).I tried to put value for background-size like **background:#00ff00 url('smiley.gif') 200px 40px 20px 20px  no-repeat fixed border-box;** but It didn't work ;

Comment: So why are you asking about `animation` when your question actually concerns `background`? Spec says [`background-size` needs to be preceeded by a `/` character](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#ltbg-layergt) in the `background` shorthand property, and `background-color` should be the final value.

Comment: My query is regarding one-line declaration of css properties .It came because it didn't work in case of background setting.As you said background-size comes with / char , I've tried it but still  facing issue. Here is what I set **background:url('smiley.gif') 200px 40px /20px 20px no-repeat fixed border-box #00ff00**

Comment: Your issue is with a _specific shorthand property_, not with shorthand properties in general, so it makes absolutely no sense to ask about one property when you actually have trouble with a completely unrelated property. Have you tried it with a space on _both_ sides of the `/`? _Absolutely all_ examples in the specs include spaces on both sides.

Comment: Yes,It works.Actually I was referring w3school doc for css practicing and there they havn't mentioned the '\' char in background prop .That's why the confusion arose because it is mentioned there if we skip any value browser take the default value for it .Suppose I'm setting position and size of background like 20px 30px .Here I wanted to set position as 20px and (50%) default and size as 30px and (auto) default but it wasn't working .So I asked the question regarding css value matching. here is the link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: ___Do not use w3schools.com as reference.___ It is [known to contain incomplete, incorrect, misleading and useless information](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19756/discussion-between-radhe001-and-lanzz)